# Unable to add play event with iframe video

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I am using iframe to play embedded videos links from different sites. I want to attach an `onplay` event with the video. Here is what I have been trying to do:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" width="420" height="315" src="some url" >
</iframe>
```

```
$('#myFrame').load(function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("video").addEventListener("click", test, false);
    
    
    });
```

I tried many solutions but i couldn't solve this problem. I recently started learning js and jQuery.

Comment: src will be youtube url?

Comment: src will be from different sites